# TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

> ## TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("D2").setValue(99)`

*Please look into the screenshot* All i want to set the value into the sheet with given range.

[Code.gs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBCHM.png)

[sheat01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfmFb.png)

**Here is the code**

```
function myF() {
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var g_as = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var as = g_as.getActiveSheet();
as.getRange("D2").setValue(99);
```

}

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please follow the guidelines of [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén i have updated now you can look into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this and it works.  The Logger comes back with the word Range.  I had no expectation that it would come back with anything.

```
function myF()
{
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').setValue(99);
}
```

It changes O19 to 99 every time.

Whenever I start getting weird stuff going on I shut down the browser and come back up and that generally does the trick.

Comment: I'm guessing you should shut down your browser and bring it back up.  I have wierd problems every so often and that's what I do.  As far as I can tell what you doing is okay.

Comment: thanks man for your response but still not working i did as you suggested me.  is there any alternative to achieving this. As i am new in GAS and this is my first app .. and unfortunately not working

Comment: Well I simplified it down to one line.  Try opening up another new spreadsheet and trying it.  This function is working on my account which is just a regular Gmail account like anyone else.