# getActiveSpreadsheet() always returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Okay, so I was following this tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/aPJ-2U45BpA) about how to set up a simple Google App Script and I was stuck at around the [18:50 mark](https://youtu.be/aPJ-2U45BpA?t=18m50s). I was getting an error message while doning the exact same thing as in the video.

I have this code in my Code.gs file:

```
function myFunction() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  

  activeSheet.getRange("D2").setValue(99);

}
```

and a spreadsheet open in another tab. But everytime I try to run "myFunction" I get the following error message:

`TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null. (line 5, file "Code")`

So for some reason `var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();` apperently returns null. It works when I replace that line with `var ss = app.openById('MySpreadsheetIdHere');`, but hard coding the id is really not what I want, I'd like to make this script work with any arbitrary opened spreadsheet.

Running the code via Run > Test as add-on doesn't work either.

From [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132895/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getactivesheet-of-null) I gathered that it seems to be hard to reproduce this problem, here's exact steps to reproduce:

1. open up chrome in guest mode, no extensions or anything
2. sign in to google drive with my google account
3. create a spreadsheet and keep it open
4. go to script.google.com and sign in with that same google account
5. create a new project and copy/paste the code from above
6. run "myFunction"
   6a. confirm permissions when running it for the first time
7. get the error

Anyone see what I missed?

Comment: Is your script spreadsheet bound? You won't be able to get the active spreadsheet from the standalone GS file. The script can only be created from the spreadsheet itself (Tools -> Script Editor).

Comment: Ahh yeah thanks, that worked! If I create the script from the spreadsheet, then that script has access to getActiveSpreadsheet(). But is there a way to write a reusable app script that I can apply to other spreadsheets as well?

Comment: Yes, use a file picker or publish it as an add-on and install it to the desired sheets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the step around [2:16 mark](https://youtu.be/aPJ-2U45BpA?t=2m16s) create a bounded script: Tools > Script editor...