# getRange Problems, Google Apps Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to run this code on Google scripts but running into the following error -TypeError: Cannot call 'getRange' method of null ('code' file, line 5)

The code is below. Any help is truly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
function myFunction() {
 var d = new Date();
 var hours = d.getHours();
 var currentTime = d.toLocaleDateString();
 var counter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').getValues();

 if (hours >= 6 && hours <= 18) {
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("url");
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('S' + counter).setValue('Visted at ' + currentTime + ' ' + hours + 'h');
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(Number(counter) + 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105012/getactivespreadsheet-always-returns-null

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getActiveSpreadsheet() always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105012/getactivespreadsheet-always-returns-null)

Comment: Hey @홍석현 were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using is not bound to a Spreadsheet. In this case, the function `getActiveSheet()` will behave just as `getActiveSpreadsheet()`:

> Returns the currently active spreadsheet, **or null if there is none**.

Effectively returning `null`.

#### Solution

In order to be able to interact with your Spreadsheet you can:

1. Create a brand new script bound to the Spreadsheet you are trying to work with. To do so, from the Sheets UI (with your Spreadsheet open), go to Tools>Script editor. There, you will be able to use the functions described above.
2. Use any of the [`open()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) functions defined in [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) from a standalone script in order to interact with your Spreadsheet.